# How to detect wrongly encoded strings in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose to have string like this one:

```
Çë½ÌÎªÊ²Ã´ÎÒÒ»½øÐÐ²é¶¾Ê±¾Í·¢ÏÖÏµÍ³ÅÌ¿ÉÓÃ¿Õ ¼ä¾Í¼±¾ç¼õÉÙ£
```

They have been wrongly encoded. How do you think it's possible to know if in fact, it's wrongly encoded?
An example of right encoded string would be

```
Ciao mamm@ guardà come mi divertò
```

I tough that there are 2 mayor differences among the 2:

- Numer of whitespaces/string_lenght
- Number of vocals(aeiou)/string_lenght

Than the code would be something like

```
if({Numer of whitespaces/string_lenght} < 0.05 (1 every 20 other characters)}
     OR {Number of vocals(aeiou)/string_lenght} < 0.2 (1 every 5 other characters)})
  return WRONG
else
  return OK
```

Do you have any better idea? Maybe there is some php function already tested that fits my case? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check the charset of string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037363/how-to-check-the-charset-of-string)

Comment: No, it's a different question ;)

Comment: What, exactly, counts as "wrongly encoded"? Do you mean that character data is reported (e.g. in an HTTP header, or the character set of a database column) to have one encoding, but should have another? Is the sample string supposed to be the latin1 code points of the characters shown, or the UTF-8 code points that actually appear in the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the encoding should be, use [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding). If you don't know what the encoding should be, try [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding), which returns `FALSE` if no valid encoding is found.

Comment: No, that won't work. The string in this case are valid latin1, but they are meaningless. Also mb_check_encoding don't check if every character is valid, it only checks if the stream is valid ;)

Comment: Then you'd need to base it on the frequency of characters in the expected language and or use pspell