# PHP: SHA-256 force in UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, sha256

Here's my problem with PHP: For E-payment integration with Postfinance, I need to verify the data send and received with a SHA-256 hash of all the fields, with a secret key between each one.

How can you be sure that the input string will be in UTF-8 just before the hashing?

The command utf8_encode() is used on the input string, and if I check with mb_check_encoding(), it's okay. I have the good response, and if I use mb_detect_encoding(), the response is "ASCII".

```
$pf_post = array();

$pf_post['AMOUNT'] = 100;
$pf_post['CURRENCY'] = "CHF";
$pf_post['ORDERID'] = 101;
$pf_post['TITLE'] = "Paiement";

$pf_key = "mytestkey";

foreach (array_keys($pf_post) as $lakey)
{
    $pf_string .= strtoupper($lakey) . "=" . strval($pf_post[$lakey]) . $pf_key;
}

$pf_string = utf8_encode($pf_string);
$pf_sign = hash('sha256',$pf_string);

if (mb_check_encoding($pf_string, 'UTF-8')) {
    $debug .= "STRING => Détection UTF8 OK !<br>";
}
else {
    $debug .= "STRING => Détection UTF8 !!! ERREUR !!!<br>";
}

if (mb_check_encoding($pf_sign, 'UTF-8')) {
    $debug .= "HASH => Détection UTF8 OK !<br>";
}
else {
    $debug .= "HASH => Détection UTF8 !!! ERREUR !!!<br>";
}

$debug .= "String Format: " . mb_detect_encoding($pf_string) .
          ", Hash Format: " . mb_detect_encoding($pf_sign) . "<br>";
```

And here's the debug:

```
STRING => Détection UTF8 OK !
HASH => Détection UTF8 OK !
String Format : ASCII, Hash Format : ASCII
```

If I use only digits in the fields, it will be okay ... if I use letters, it will be not every time okay ... and if use letters with accent ... it's wrong anytime!

In HTML header, I have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037368/1461181

Comment: _“the command utf8_encode() is used on the input string”_ - why, is it not UTF-8 already? We are talking about form data here, right? Your page is in UTF-8 already, so how did you manage to get form data send _not_ as UTF-8 in the first place?

Comment: Or are you just talking about the `$pf_post` data here? If that is not UTF-8 already, it means you did not save your script file itself as UTF-8 - so _that_ would be the thing you need to correct, and not mess with encodings at runtime ...

Comment: `utf8_encode()` ==  is your input string sure to be ***only*** `ISO-8859-1` type?

Comment: Thank for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

```
$str = "éóùùééééè"; // Will output 'éóùùééééè'
$strr = utf8_encode($str); // Will output 'Ã©Ã³Ã¹Ã¹Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã¨'
```

If you apply to an UTF-8 string, utf8_encode() will return a garbled UTF-8 output as shown in the example.

To ensure that you are using UTF-8, at the top of every script use `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` and you can use this [forceutf8 class](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8).

```
<?php
    // Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

    include('Encoding.php'); // The class from GitHub

    // Same strings
    $str = 'éóùùééééè';
    $str1 = 'Ã©Ã³Ã¹Ã¹Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã¨'; //garbled UTF8 of éóùùééééè

    // Force input to UTF-8
    use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;
    echo Encoding::fixUTF8($str).'</br>'; // Will output éóùùééééè
    echo Encoding::fixUTF8($str1).'</br>'; // Will output éóùùééééè

    $str3 = Encoding::fixUTF8($str);
    $str4 = Encoding::fixUTF8($str1);


    // Then hash
    $hash1 = hash('sha256', $str3);
    $hash1 = hash('sha256', $str4);

    echo $hash1; // Will output 45b8151559a5136d58f85ebf51c24f26c47e51f4a89fe2962c8626e99ad64786
    echo $hash2; // Will output 45b8151559a5136d58f85ebf51c24f26c47e51f4a89fe2962c8626e99ad64786

    // mb_detect_encoding will always output ASCII
    echo  mb_detect_encoding($hash1). '</br>'; // Will output ASCII
    echo  mb_detect_encoding($hash1); //// Will output ASCII
```

And at the browser level you need:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thank you for this very complete demo !

Answer (score 0):

You should not encode the values to UTF-8 twice. I would suggest to encode only if really necessary. Example:

```
if (!mb_check_encoding($pf_string, 'UTF-8')) {
    $pf_string = mb_convert_encoding($pf_string, 'UTF-8');
}
```