# How to find out the Encoding of a File? C#

Tags: c#

Well i need to find out which of the files i found in some directory is UTF8 Encoded either ANSI encoded to change the Encoding in something else i decide later. My problem is.. how can i find out if a file is UTF8 or ANSI Encoded? Both of the encodings are actually posible in my files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no reliable way to do it (since the file might be just random binary), however the process done by Windows Notepad software is detailed in Micheal S Kaplan's blog:

http://www.siao2.com/2007/04/22/2239345.aspx

> 1. Check the first two bytes;
>           1. If there is a UTF-16 LE BOM, then treat it (and load it) as a "Unicode" file;
>           2. If there is a UTF-16 BE BOM, then treat it (and load it) as a "Unicode (Big Endian)" file;
>           3. If the first two bytes look like the start of a UTF-8 BOM, then check the next byte and if we have a UTF-8 BOM, then treat it (and load it) as a "UTF-8" file;
> 2. Check with IsTextUnicode to see if that function think it is BOM-less UTF-16 LE, if so, then treat it (and load it) as a "Unicode" file;
> 3. Check to see if it UTF-8 using the original RFC 2279 definition  from 1998 and if it then treat it (and load it) as a "UTF-8" file;
> 4. Assume an ANSI file using the default system code page of the machine.
>
> Now note that there are some holes
>   here, like the fact that step 2 does
>   not do quite as good with BOM-less
>   UTF-16 BE (there may even be a bug
>   here, I'm not sure -- if so it's a bug
>   in Notepad beyond any bug in
>   IsTextUnicode).

Comment: StreamReader does this automatically if you pass `true` for the `detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks` parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I did not know .net had internal support for this procedure!

Comment: In my tests, the ´detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks´ flags does not detect ANSI encoding

Comment: Definitely the StreamReader can't detect ANSI.

Comment: @ICantSeeSharp How-to ***detect*** `ANSI` ?

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569610.aspx#Question2

> There is no great way to detect an
>   arbitrary ANSI code page, though there
>   have been some attempts to do this
>   based on the probability of certain
>   byte sequences in the middle of text.
>   We don't try that in StreamReader. A
>   few file formats like XML or HTML have
>   a way of specifying the character set
>   on the first line in the file, so Web
>   browsers, databases, and classes like
>   XmlTextReader can read these files
>   correctly. But many text files don't
>   have this type of information built
>   in.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode/UTF8/UnicodeBigEndian are considered to be different types. ANSI is considered the same as UTF8.

```
public class EncodingType
{
    public static System.Text.Encoding GetType(string FILE_NAME)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Encoding r = GetType(fs);
        fs.Close();
        return r;
    }

    public static System.Text.Encoding GetType(FileStream fs)
    {
        byte[] Unicode = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x41 };
        byte[] UnicodeBIG = new byte[] { 0xFE, 0xFF, 0x00 };
        byte[] UTF8 = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF }; //with BOM
        Encoding reVal = Encoding.Default;

        BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        int i;
        int.TryParse(fs.Length.ToString(), out i);
        byte[] ss = r.ReadBytes(i);
        if (IsUTF8Bytes(ss) || (ss[0] == 0xEF && ss[1] == 0xBB && ss[2] == 0xBF))
        {
            reVal = Encoding.UTF8;
        }
        else if (ss[0] == 0xFE && ss[1] == 0xFF && ss[2] == 0x00)
        {
            reVal = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
        }
        else if (ss[0] == 0xFF && ss[1] == 0xFE && ss[2] == 0x41)
        {
            reVal = Encoding.Unicode;
        }
        r.Close();
        return reVal;

    }

    private static bool IsUTF8Bytes(byte[] data)
    {
        int charByteCounter = 1;　 
        byte curByte; 
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            curByte = data[i];
            if (charByteCounter == 1)
            {
                if (curByte >= 0x80)
                {
                    while (((curByte <<= 1) & 0x80) != 0)
                    {
                        charByteCounter++;
                    }
                    　
                    if (charByteCounter == 1 || charByteCounter > 6)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((curByte & 0xC0) != 0x80)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                charByteCounter--;
            }
        }
        if (charByteCounter > 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error byte format");
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks like a great bit of code. However, isn't UTF16 LE and UTF16-BE supposed to have the signature "FF FE" and "FE FF" respectively? You've added an extra byte. See: http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom4

Comment: By the way, how does your IsUTF8Bytes() function compare to Christoph's answer shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1031773/848344

Comment: @DanW: I don't know where is Christoph's answer from, the code I posted is part of the project I've worked, written by a teammate.

Comment: I suggest using the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yh598w02.aspx) instead of manually closing/disposing the objects just to ensure these get disposed even in case of an unexpected exception.

Answer (score 0):

See these two codeproject articles - it is not trivial to find out file encoding simply from the file content:

- [Detect encoding from ByteOrderMarks (BOM)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/BomDetecting.aspx)
- [Detect Encoding for In- and Outgoing Text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
   public static System.Text.Encoding GetEncoding(string filepath, Encoding defaultEncoding)
    {
        // will fall to defaultEncoding if file does not have BOM

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filepath, defaultEncoding, true))
        {
            reader.Peek(); //need it
            return reader.CurrentEncoding;
        }
    }
```

Check [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

To see the BOM you need to see file in a hexadecimal view.

Notepad show the file encoding at status bar, but it can be just estimated, if the file hasn't the BOM set.

Comment: I tried this, and everthing (UTF-16-BE, LE, ansi and utf8) all brought back utf-8. :<