# Determine File Encoding: Unicode or ANSI

Tags: unicode, encoding, installation, nsis

I am using the Unicode version of NSIS to make an installer. I will be appending lines to both ANSI and Unicode files. Before I write a line to a file I need to know whether the file is ANSI encoded or Unicode so I know if I should use **FileWrite** or **FileWriteUTF16LE**.

**How can I find out the encoding type of a file?**

The [Unicode Plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Unicode_plug-in) which can tell me the encoding of a file doesn't work for *NSIS Unicode*, the function **unicode::UnicodeType** always returns 6.

Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using that plugin you could recompile it yourself as unicode or try the [CallAnsiPlugin plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CallAnsiPlugin_plug-in).

You can also perform the check yourself:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

!define ByHandleIsFileUTF16LE "'' ByHandleIsFileUTF16LE "
!macro _ByHandleIsFileUTF16LE a b t f
!insertmacro _LOGICLIB_TEMP
FileReadByte ${b} $_LOGICLIB_TEMP
IntCmpU $_LOGICLIB_TEMP 0xFF "" `${f}`
FileReadByte ${b} $_LOGICLIB_TEMP
IntCmpU $_LOGICLIB_TEMP 0xFE `${t}` `${f}`
!macroend
!define IsFileUTF16LE "'' IsFileUTF16LE "
!macro _IsFileUTF16LE a b t f
!insertmacro _LOGICLIB_TEMP
Push $0
FileOpen $0 "${b}" r
!define _IsFileUTF16LE _IsFileUTF16LE${__LINE__}
!insertmacro _ByHandleIsFileUTF16LE '' $0 ${_IsFileUTF16LE}t ${_IsFileUTF16LE}f
${_IsFileUTF16LE}f:
    StrCpy $_LOGICLIB_TEMP ""
${_IsFileUTF16LE}t:
!undef _IsFileUTF16LE
FileClose $0
Pop $0
StrCmp "" $_LOGICLIB_TEMP `${f}` `${t}`
!macroend



section

!macro testutf16detection file
${If} ${IsFileUTF16LE} "${file}"
    DetailPrint "${file} is UTF16LE"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "${file} is NOT UTF16LE"
${EndIf}
!macroend

!insertmacro testutf16detection "$temp\test1.txt"
!insertmacro testutf16detection "$temp\test2.txt"

sectionend
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to check for the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding). Here's how you could check if a file uses the UTF16LE encoding:

```
!define fileIsUTF16LE "!insertmacro FileIsUTF16LE"
!macro FileIsUTF16LE file result
  Push $0
  Push $1
  FileOpen $0 "${file}" r
  FileReadByte $0 $1
  IntCmpU $1 0xFF "" FileIsUTF16LE_ItsNot FileIsUTF16LE_ItsNot
  FileReadByte $0 $1
  IntCmpU $1 0xFE FileIsUTF16LE_ItIs FileIsUTF16LE_ItsNot FileIsUTF16LE_ItsNot
  FileIsUTF16LE_ItIs:
    StrCpy ${result} 1
    Goto FileIsUTF16LE_Done
  FileIsUTF16LE_ItsNot:
    StrCpy ${result} 0
  FileIsUTF16LE_Done:
    FileClose $0
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
!macroend
```

Usage:

```
${fileIsUTF16LE} "$R0" $3
${If} $3 == 1
```

Note that this will not work in all cases since not all UTF encodings require a BOM. You could easily modify this macro to check for [other BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)s, however, definitively determining encoding is [non trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404199/how-to-find-out-the-encoding-of-a-file-c-sharp). One method would be to  check for all the different BOMs, if the file doesn't have a BOM, assume it's not unicode.