# byte[] to string without knowing the coding

Tags: c#, decoding

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/byte-to-string-in-c-sharp) answer, The problem is - so I also need to know what type of encoder to use for getting the correct string - it may be in UTF\UTF8\ANSI.

Here is a example from the immediate window.

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(combinedBuf)
"믯ힿ힩힜힕�"
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(combinedBuf)
"﻿שלום"
```

Comment: I don't know that this makes sense. What you want is like asking a compiler to compile text and figure out whether it's in C, Java, or FORTRAN.

Comment: You should *somehow guess* the encoding.

Comment: I think what you want to do is detect which encoding was used? See the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404199/how-to-find-out-the-encoding-of-a-file-c-sharp

Comment: @Cocowalla Put the answer and I will mark it as accepted - Or someone mark this as duplicate