# check input for UTF-8, count characters, use regular expressions

Tags: mysql, c, regex, utf-8

I want to write a C-program that gets some strings from input. I want to save them in a MySQL database.
For security I would like to check, if the input is a (possible) UTF-8 string, count the number of characters and also use some regular expressions to validate the input.

Is there a library that offers me that functionality?

I thought about to use wide characters, but as far as I understood, the fact if they are supporting UTF-8 depends on the implementation and ist not defined by a standard.
And also I would be missing the regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

[PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) supports UTF-8. To validate the string before any processing, the W3C suggests [this expression](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8), which I [re-implemented in plain C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031645/how-to-detect-utf-8-in-plain-c/1031773#1031773), but PCRE already automatically checks for UTF-8 in accordance to RFC 3629.

Comment: +1 I hated the question (I don't like regexps), and you had such a neat answer.