# how to find the encoding type of configuration.properties files in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

$encoding = get-content -path 'specified the path'
$encoding

## need the encoding type of  file extension of .properties  (not .ps1 or XML file  ) for example: configuration.properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28079177/1701026)

Comment: when iam opening the encoding.property file in notepad++ it was showing Shift-jis encoding format so it was not the answer in that code there is no Shift-jis encoding

Comment: @iRon can you check it once about the issue

Comment: Please, open a new question with the concerned detals and what you have tried. I recommend you to have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Did some research, and **Shift-jis** appears to be a very specific encoding (which yiu didn't mentioned in your question anywhere). Apperently, [if the file is not valid UTF-8 then it's Shift-JIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64095905/1701026).