# Can StreamReader read all encodings by default?

Tags: c#, .net

In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `StreamReader`, it says:

```
StreamReader defaults to UTF-8 encoding unless specified otherwise
```

Does that mean when I read a file, it will treat this file as UTF-8 encoded?
Or does it mean something else, because I have tested reading a UTF-16LE encoded file and it worked without a problem.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("D:\\1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(str);
sr.Close();
```

Comment: This one can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746530/auto-encoding-detect-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Orace So `StreamReader` will attempt to detect known encodings, but if it did not recognize any, it will treat the file as UTF-8?

Comment: If you don't specify the Encoding explicitly then StreamReader will try to auto-detect it from the file.  If it can't figure it out then it falls back to utf8.  That usually turns out well for a file that contains utf16 encoded text, such a file usually has a BOM.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, the simple way to know the answer is to perform some tests:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var bytes1 = new byte[] {0x00, 0x61, 0x25, 0x54};
        var bytes2 = new byte[] {0xFE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x61, 0x25, 0x54};
        var bytes3 = new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFE, 0x61, 0x00, 0x54, 0x25};

        Write(bytes1); // Writes: ' a%T'
        Write(bytes2); // Writes: 'a╔'
        Write(bytes3); // Writes: 'a╔'

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Write(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                var str = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if the stream first 2 bytes are the byte order mask ([BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) of <s>UTF-16</s> Unicode (LE or BE), the stream will be read as a <s>UTF-16</s> Unicode stream. Otherwise it will be read as a UTF-8 one.

**[Edit]**

Strangely the [StreamReader Constructor (Stream, Encoding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains informations that the [StreamReader Constructor (Stream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yhfzs7at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not have.

> The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at
>   the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes
>   UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file
>   starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the
>   user-provided encoding is used.

First remark here : **the user-provided encoding is not necessarily used**.

Now if you look at the [reference implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs), the constructor with only a `Stream` as parameter is in fact a call to:

```
StreamReader(stream: stream, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true, bufferSize: DefaultBufferSize, leaveOpen: false)
```

So the informations above applies.

More precisely, it is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg712952%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter is true, the
>   constructor detects the encoding by looking at the first three bytes
>   of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian
>   Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the
>   appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is
>   used.