# What is the most common encoding of each language?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I am developing a plain-text reader application. Sometimes app can't auto determine the encoding of a file, so user needs select an encoding from a list of encodings. If this list contains all supported encodings, it will be too long. I want to provide a simplified list, only contains most common encodings of each language.

This is some relationship I am known:

- Traditional Chinese: Big5
- Simplified Chinese: GB18030
- Japanese: Shift-JIS, EUC-JP
- Russian: KOI8-R

If you know any other language's most common encoding, please tell me.

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out the Unicode families? UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are definitely used at least as much as the ones you named.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Yes, I need a list of regional encodings, exclude Unicode encodings. For example, GB18030 is national standard of PRC, so it is widely used in mainland China.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

On the web, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is by far the most common encoding [for all languages](https://w3techs.com/technologies/breakdown/en-utf8/content_language).

That being said, here are the Windows XP locales grouped by default character encoding ("[Language for non-Unicode programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/system-locale)"):

- **Big5**: zh_HK, zh_MO, zh_TW
- **GBK** (≈GB2312): zh_CN, zh_SG
- **Windows-31J** (≈Shift_JIS): ja_JP
- **windows-874** (≈TIS-620, ISO-8859-11): th_TH
- **windows-949** (≈EUC-KR): ko_KR
- **windows-1250**: bs_BA, cs_CZ, hr_BA, hr_HR, hu_HU, pl_PL, ro_RO, sk_SK, sl_SI, sq_AL, sr_BA, sr_SP
- **windows-1251**: az_AZ, be_BY, bg_BG, kk_KZ, ky_KG, mk_MK, mn_MN, ru_RU, sr_BA, sr_SP, tt_RU, uk_UA, uz_UZ
- **windows-1252** (≈ISO-8859-1): af_ZA, arn_CL, ca_ES, cy_GB, da_DK, de_AT, de_CH, de_DE, de_LI, de_LU, en_AU, en_BZ, en_CA, en_CB, en_GB, en_IE, en_JM, en_NZ, en_PH, en_TT, en_US, en_ZA, en_ZW, es_AR, es_BO, es_CL, es_CO, es_CR, es_DO, es_EC, es_ES, es_GT, es_HN, es_MX, es_NI, es_PA, es_PE, es_PR, es_PY, es_SV, es_UY, es_VE, eu_ES, fi_FI, fil_PH, fo_FO, fr_BE, fr_CA, fr_CH, fr_FR, fr_LU, fr_MC, fy_NL, ga_IE, gl_ES, id_ID, is_IS, it_CH, it_IT, iu_CA, iv_IV, lb_LU, moh_CA, ms_BN, ms_MY, nb_NO, nl_BE, nl_NL, nn_NO, ns_ZA, pt_BR, pt_PT, qu_BO, qu_EC, qu_PE, rm_CH, se_FI, se_NO, se_SE, sv_FI, sv_SE, sw_KE, tn_ZA, xh_ZA, zu_ZA
- **windows-1253**: el_GR
- **windows-1254** (≈ISO-8859-9): az_AZ, tr_TR, uz_UZ
- **windows-1255**: he_IL
- **windows-1256**: ar_AE, ar_BH, ar_DZ, ar_EG, ar_IQ, ar_JO, ar_KW, ar_LB, ar_LY, ar_MA, ar_OM, ar_QA, ar_SA, ar_SY, ar_TN, ar_YE, fa_IR, ps_AF, ur_PK
- **windows-1257**: et_EE, lt_LT, lv_LV
- **windows-1258**: vi_VN

and the [most common encodings overall on the Web as of October 30th 2020](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/character_encoding/all):

1. UTF-8    95.7%
2. [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)  1.8%
3. [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)    1.0%
4. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)    0.4%
5. [GB2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312)  0.3%
6. [Shift JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS)   0.2%
7. GBK  0.1%
8. EUC-KR   0.1%
9. ISO-8859-9   0.1%
10. Windows-1254 0.1%
11. EUC-JP   0.1%
12. Big5 0.1%

Answer (score 6):

The HTML5 draft contains a table of [default encodings for languages](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding), reflecting what is regarded as common. However, note that it is supposed to be based on the *user* locale, i.e. the language of the browser or the operating system, not the language of the *document*—obviously because the latter is usually unknown, at least before you actually read the document, based on some assumption about the encoding.

I think you could in practice copy the list of encodings in a popular web browser. If it works well there, it probably works reasonably well in your application. Browsers do some clever things with the list and its order, but in practice, I think it would suffice to have a short list like utf-8, utf-16, windows-1252, and maybe a few others, followed by an option of getting the full list. Note that although utf-16 is practically unused and useless for web pages, it is common for plain text files around. It is important to name the encodings well, preferably with a common English (or other language) name together with the IANA “charset” name in parentheses—much like browsers do.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the menu structure like the one used by browsers. For instance Firefox: View -> Character Encoding -> More Encoding -> East Asian -> Chinese/Japanese/Korean.
(ok, easier if you just look). And View -> Encoding -> More in IE.

Might seem too deep and clunky, but it is very familiar. And does not drop useful encodings (Why KOI8-R for Russian, for instance? And what happens if I use Windows 1251 and is not in the list?)