# Decode error - output not utf-8 - pandas/python 2.7/excel/win

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas

I am starting to play with pandas.

I downloaded a google sheet.

When reading some data from excel in win7:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/file.xlsx')
data = xls.parse('Sheet 1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
print "Data", data
```

I am a getting:

```
Decode error - output not utf-8
```

The original excel file has text and numbers.

What is wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a different encoding argument such as `iso-8859-1`. Here is an exhaustive [list from the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml). Though data may look like legitimate Latin numbers and text, one character could require a different character set, depending on origination.

Also you can either use the two step process, `ExcelFile` or one-step process, `read_excel`:

**ExcelFile**

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/file.xlsx')
data = xls.parse('Sheet 1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], encoding='iso-8859-1')
print data.head()
```

**read_excel**

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/file.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', encoding='iso-8859-1')
print data.head()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately so far none worked. I will keep on trying.

Comment: Try this popular encoding list [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509339/what-is-the-most-common-encoding-of-each-language). Usually character sets depend on language of file's origin.

Comment: Thank you for the list. The google sheet I am importing is mine. I think there might be a format issue when I download it to an excel file on my pc. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the encoding of your data changes from ASCII to latin1. try this encoding **cp1252**