# Get string dump from file

Tags: c#

A long time ago, I remember using an utility which dumps all (ASCII/UTF8) strings from an executable file.
I'm now wondering how could I go about implementing this in C#.

Currently, I use an external utility that dumps the strings to a file, and then I read that file from my application. 
I'd now like to replace the external utility with some sort of a parser in C#.

How does the dump strings utility detect UTF8 string in a file, and how can I implement this in C#?

Comment: it seem explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp). For easiness: http://utf8checker.codeplex.com/

Comment: That will determine whether the _whole_ file/stream is in whichever encoding. What I need is to extract strings from (binary) files.

Comment: I wrote a program many years ago that would locate and output ASCII/UTF8 strings. I never tried to make it do UTF-8. The source (in C) is available at http://mischel.com/toolutil/strings.zip. Shouldn't be too difficult to convert to C#.

Comment: re: the above. The program outputs ASCII and *Unicode* strings, not UTF-8.