# windows 8 phone webbrowser navigatetostring does not work when meta tag <meta charset=""utf-8""> is present

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebBrowser test = new WebBrowser();

        string tes1t = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Sample Page</title>
        <meta charset=""utf-8"">
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>sample html Navigate to string</p>
       </body>
       </html>";
        test.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        test.ScriptNotify += test_ScriptNotify;
        test.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        test.NavigateToString(tes1t);
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(test);


        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    void test_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

in the above sample code when the webbrowser navigates to string with the given html5 text, the rendering is  proper, but  when i remove the meta tag, the navigation is correct, not able to figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the .NET character encoding used in your string variable is *not* UTF-8, it is UTF-16. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025346/694641 for more discussion about this.

If you don't specify the encoding the browser will auto-detect the actual text encoding for you automatically.