# Check if string consists only of valid ISO 8859-1 characters

Tags: c#, string, encoding, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

How to check if a string consists only of chars, which can be successfully encoded in ISO 8859-1? Or in other words - how to find "illegal"/"not ISO 8859-1 compatible" chars in a string?

Comment: Would [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp) help?

Comment: @MechanicalObject: Probably not, if it is already a C# String (and not raw bytes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private static bool IsValidISO(string input)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(input);
        String result = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes);
        return String.Equals(input, result);
    }
```

This answer is based on an answer of this Java question (my code is the C# equivalent):
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t137810-checking-whether-a-string-contains-only-iso-8859-1-chars.html

Comment: This looks better than mine idea. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @netblognet You're welcome! I also looked at your code, but it looks "dangerous" because you can't be 100% sure that non-ISO chars will give a question mark. My code is also faster.

Comment: Great answer. Small suggestion even if it is a really old post. 
Instead of 
Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1") 
use 
Encoding.Latin1

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an array or list of valid characters and then iterate through your string to check if each of them exists in your list of valid characters. The list can be created by adding all valid latin-1 characters to it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this idea. Might this be possible?

```
    private static bool IsValidISO(string input)
    {
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

            byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(c.ToString());
            byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso, utf8, isoBytes);

            string convertedC = utf8.GetString(utfBytes);
            if (c != '?' && convertedC == "?")
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```