# How to determine text format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, format

Is there a way to determine the format of text in C#/.NET

something like this would be very useful.

```
public TextFormat TextTools.GetTextFormat(string text);

switch(TextTools.GetTextFormat(mystring))
{

  case TextFormat.RichText: break;
  case TextFormat.PlainText: break;

}
```

Ive looked around on msdn but couldnt find such a tool

Comment: Maybe try looking around on stackoverflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp

Comment: @sgrassie encoding and rich\plain text formats are different aspects of a text

Comment: @IlyaIvanov yes, of course.

Comment: We can use regular expression to return true or false.                 string sPattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}$";                                         if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtValue, sPattern)){ }

Comment: @karthik what it should match?

Answer (score 8):

It's a pretty heuristic check but you can try to build your own function starting with something like this (of course you can extend it to handle different formats):

```
public static TextFormat GetFormat(string text) {
    if (text.TrimStart().StartsWith(@"{\rtf", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        return TextFormat.RichText;

    return TextFormat.PlainText;
}
```

A better check implies you parse RTF text to be sure it's not just a *random* string that seems RTF. Because parsing may be expansive (in terms of time) then I'd suggest to first do a quick check to exclude everything for sure isn't RTF:

```
public static TextFormat GetFormat(string text) {
    if (text.TrimStart().StartsWith(@"{\rtf", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
        if (IsValidRtf(text))
            return TextFormat.RichText;
    }

    return TextFormat.PlainText;
}
```

In the most nested `if` you can decide what to do with text that seems RTF but it's not valid (in this example I just consider it as plain text). A possible, naive and inefficient, implementation of `IsValidRtf()` that relies on `RichTextBox` control implementation (then down to Windows API implementation) may be:

```
private static bool IsValidRtf(string text) {
    try {
        new RichTextBox().Rtf = text;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) {
        return false;
    }
        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Its better to just check for `@"{\rtf"` because not all richtext is rtf1 like visual studio text is just rtf

Comment: I was under the impression that the _version_ field was mandatory but if you found an editor that does not emit it then...good catch!