# Check if a file is TXT or RTF with no extension

Tags: c#

I have a system that processes TXT files and RTF files and converts them using a 3rd party tool. I have to integrate with another system that produces files with a .RTF extension but are actually just .TXT files. Unfortunately there is no consistent file names or text to search for. I have no control over the source files.

Is there a way in c# to check if a file has an RTF file header so I can establish if the file is RTF or TXT without using the extension?

This is part of a web application so I dont want to automate opening MS word or any other bulky tools to check if a file is RTF or not.

Comment: A txt file has no content requirements. Literally any file is a valid "txt" file.

Comment: The RTF magic number is `{\rtf1`. You could try checking for that?

Comment: https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/rtf/ states that rtf file start with a header `\rtf1\fbidis`

Comment: tnx, I also Just found this, trying it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502924/how-to-determine-text-format-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Julia well, [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502924/how-to-determine-text-format-in-c-sharp#comment112021001_22503136)