# C# httprequest httpresponce decoding

Tags: c#, httprequest, decoding

I can`t find the way out...

I`m working with some website through`HTTPRequests`. in the page content, I receive a symbols like this:

```
u0432\u0438\u043a\u0438
```

what is it? how can I decode it, using C#?

Comment: They're Cyrillic characters [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0438/index.htm) is one one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var src= "\u0438"; 
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetBytes(src)));
```

Assuming you're using UTF-8.
If the values don't check, please view this link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks! that works. i was so confused, what kind of encoding it would be. Thought some cryptography

Comment: when i put the string 

`string token = "\u041e\u0448\u0438\u0431";`
`string decoded = (Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetBytes(token)));`
inside of the code - everything works ok.
but when i`m reseiving the totally same string from the website - it doesn`t works, i just getting the same string back.
why is it can happened?

i used an encoding determination methods from here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp
and getting the result what in the httpresponse i`m getting a "unicode" string.

Comment: that's weird, maybe you're not parsing the string in a proper way?by the way are you supposed to receive that kind of symbols? In the dark part of the internet that may be used as a sort of attack

Comment: already found a solution - just parse a JSON response by the newton.json library. it fixes this prob with this symbols.

sort of attack, receiving a response from server? how?

Comment: i'm glad you found a way to fix this :) if you're receiving this symbols from a trustful source i guess there's no problem, i thought in the beginning you weren't aware of the source, so it could be for example an homograph attack